# Translation for "Example configuration"

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm trying to find a translation for "Example configuration" for a technical documentation.

Should I use "Configuration de exemple"?

Comment: If you're stumbling on this, it does not bode well for the rest of the translation...

Comment: What does example configuration even mean?

Comment: Why are you not paying a translation service for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the context.

If the configuration is just a generic example, then the correct translation would be

> Exemple de configuration.

If the configuration is one used for a previous example, then the translation is

> Configuration de l'exemple.

Answer (score 1):

If an "example" is configured, then say:

> configuration de l'exemple

(but I really don't think that you want to say that)

If you talking about a possibility for a computer configuration (more probable), then say:

> exemple de configuration